# Parsing DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, iformatprovider

How would one parse 1900-01-01 00:00:00Z into a DateTime object?

```
        string temp = "1900-01-01 00:00:00Z";
        CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        var date = DateTime.ParseExact(temp, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ssZ", provider);
```

this returns me:

12/31/1899 7:00:00 PM

Comment: The time is off by 5 hours exactly. You probably need to take timezone into account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How are you displaying the value? I suspect it's just applying your local time zone to the date.

For example, try printing out:

- `date.Year`
- `date.Kind`
- `date.Hour`

My guess is that you'll see `date` is *actually* a UTC `DateTime` with the right value.

It's unfortunate that .NET is performing the time zone conversion for you implicitly, but then the date and time types in .NET leave something to be desired anyway :(

An alternative would be to use `DateTimeOffset` which should make it slightly clearer.

Comment: you need to a frame a screenshot

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing you are in EST.  It is subtracting 5 hours from the time.  Maybe this is because of how you printing out the time?  Try printing it in GMT.  Or you could parse it with your local timezone.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
        DateTime a;
        var dt = DateTime.TryParse("30/05/1970",out a);
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, the time given is adjusted to the local time zone of your machine. The `date.Kind` should reflect that. If instead you want the time adjusted to Universal Time (UTC), use [`DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91hfhz89.aspx) flag as the fourth parameter to `ParseExact`.